# Views Vs Temporary Table or Temporary Variables in SQL server

Tags: sql-server, database, performance, database-design, relational-database

I want to understand performance merits/demerits in using views instead of temporary tables in stored procedures in SQL Server.

I know the difference between the two (like temporary table can give stale data, etc.) but I could [not] find any info from performance perspective anywhere.

Comment: Why not test them and see? No one can accurately tell you the performance under YOUR circumstances. Build the objects, load representative data, simulate query patterns with instrumentation. Voila!

Answer (score 5):

`Views` will not give improved performance unless you have `Enterprise edition` and your view can follow the rules for an `indexed view`. Views which call other views can cause severe performance issues. `Temp tables` do have stale data, but for the purposes of a transaction with multiple actions in a proc that is a generally good thing as all actions are operating against the same set of data. That leads to fewer data integrity problems. `Table varaibles` are faster than `temp tables` in smaller sets of data generally but `temp tables` tend to perform better for the larger sets especially since they can be indexed. As with all performance tuning, there are differences depending on your particular hardware and database design, so if you are concerned about performance (as you should be) then you need to test the various options to see hwat works best for your particular instance.

Comment: Thanks for reply but could you elaborate more on "Views will not give improved performance unless you have Enterprise edition and your view can follow the rules for an indexed view"

Comment: You can use the `noexpand` hint so that indexed views are used in other editions. I did see a question on SO that indicated that this was no longer case from SQL Server 2008 R2 but am not sure about that myself.

Comment: @Abhi9, you need to read about indexed views in Books Online, there is a long, complicated set of rules for whether a view can be indexed.

Comment: In SQL 2012 SE hint Noexpand is not needed, according to documentation http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645993(v=sql.110).aspx server should automatically optimize for better performance plan... This is changed if you compare with 2008 R2. Though I do not have SE to validate.